# ArcGIS Online popup generated by expression does not display results unless a pie chart is added

Tags: arcgis-online, expression, popup, chart

Working in AGOL, I've written a conditional expression that generates an output for my popup based on one of the layers in my map. However, the output does not display unless I also add a pie chart to the popup. I'm not sure why the expression is dependent on the pie chart but whenever I remove the chart, the output of my expression is blank. Are these two things linked in a way that I'm unaware of?

Here is an anonymized version of the expression:

```
var tops_list = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12', 'X13', 'X14', 'X15', 'X16', 'X17', 'X18', 'X19'];
var display = "";

// Create a featureset, my layer is called Countries with Active Engagement
var features = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Countries with Active Engagement')

var schema_dict = Schema(features);

var fields_array = schema_dict['fields'];

var tops = [fields_array[97], fields_array[98],
            fields_array[99], fields_array[100],
            fields_array[101], fields_array[102],
            fields_array[103], fields_array[104],
            fields_array[105], fields_array[106],
            fields_array[107], fields_array[108],
            fields_array[109], fields_array[110],
            fields_array[111], fields_array[112],
            fields_array[113], fields_array[114],
            fields_array[115]];

for (var i in tops_list) {
    if ($feature[tops_list[i]] == 3 &&
    tops_list[i] == tops[i]['name']) {
        display += '-' + " " + tops[i]['alias'] + TextFormatting.NewLine;
    }
}

return display;
```

UPDATE: I figured out that I need to have the fields in my code (X1, X2, X3, etc.) selected in the fields list when configuring my popup in order for the code output to display properly. But, I don't want all of the fields to display in the popup, just the code output. Is there a way I can get the output to display without having to select the fields/having them in the popup?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please could you add some additional information about your problem. i.e. Can you post the expression used?